# Why can I not create virtualenv using ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtualenv for nodepool user using ansible but it is failing as outlined below.  I want to become nodepool user as it uses python3.5 whereas all others use the server default, 2.7.5.  It seems that it cannot source the 3.5 version.

The play is:

```
- name: Create nodepool venv
  become: true
  become_user: nodepool
  become_method: su
  command: virtualenv-3.5 /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv
```

The error is:

```
fatal: [ca-o3lscizuul]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "virtualenv-3.5 /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

It works from shell.

```
[root@host ~]# su nodepool
[nodepool@host root]$ virtualenv-3.5 /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv
Using base prefix '/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr'
New python executable in /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Comment: Could you try absolute path for `virtualenv-3.5`?

Comment: `become_method: su` — does it run `su nodepool` or `su - nodepool`? The difference may be in `$PATH` so that ansible couldn't find `virtualenv` script or `python` binary.

Comment: I believe it does su.  This is what I did via shell for test and it worked.

Comment: Using full path also fails but with different error; "stderr": "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Using command: virtualenv {{ nodepool_home }}/npvenv creates the venv but using version 2.7.5, not 3.5 as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around the issue as follows.

shell: source /var/lib/nodepool/.bashrc && virtualenv-3.5 /var/lib/nodepool/npvenv creates="/var/lib/nodepool/npvenv"

It is not as I'd like to do it but it will do.  If anyone knows how I might do like originally posted, please advise.  Perhaps it's not possible as it doesn't pickup paths etc.

I threw in the creates option as it prevents redoing if it exists.